# EditContext IsModified is TRUE when no changes have been made

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

I am using `MudBlazor` and have a simple `EditForm`.  I cannot figure out why the `EditContext.IsModified` value is `TRUE` when **nothing** on the form has been changed. Just clicking the `Cancel` button on the form changes the `IsModified` value from `False` to `True`.

```
@if (modelUserDetails != null) {
    <EditForm EditContext="editContext" OnValidSubmit="@SaveChanges">
            <MudTextField @bind-Value="modelUserDetails.FirstName" For="@(() => modelUserDetails.FirstName)" Label="First Name" AutoFocus="true" MaxLength="30" Counter="30" Immediate="true" />
            <MudTextField @bind-Value="modelUserDetails.LastName" For="@(() => modelUserDetails.LastName)" Label="Last Name" MaxLength="30" Counter="30" Immediate="true" />
        <MudButton ButtonType="ButtonType.Button" OnClick="CancelChanges" DisableElevation="true">Cancel</MudButton>
        ...
    </EditForm>
}
```

.razor code file

```
private EditUserDTO? modelUserDetails { get; set; }
private EditContext? editContext { get; set; }

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync() {
    modelUserDetails = await UserRepository.GetSingleUser(id);
    editContext = new EditContext(modelUserDetails);
    editContext.MarkAsUnmodified();
    Console.WriteLine($"IsModified: {editContext.IsModified()}"); // False at this point
}


private async Task CancelChanges() {
    Console.WriteLine($"IsModified: {editContext.IsModified()}"); // True at this point
    
    ...
    
}
```

The code above is a cut-back version.  I simply want the `IsModified` value to **only** be `True` if any of the `MudTextField` values have been changed by the user.  What is going wrong here?

I've spent several hours trying to solve this; trying different approaches, searching online, but I have not had any success solving this.

Comment: did you test all fields of modelUserDetails for changes? use editContext .IsModified(FieldIdentifier) to find the fields that changed. may be its help you.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because your first input field is automatically focussed. It seems like Blazor will see this as a modification. I personally think this is not the right behaviour. You could try to remove the auto focus, but this won't really solve the problem, because as soon as you just click an input element without modifying its value, the same problem will occur.